# Editing 'Discount' label in Magento 2 cart

Tags: magento2, cart

In Magento 2.1, on the cart it has a line item for "Discount". I need to change that to, say, "Member Discount". Where do I do this?

I am using Magento 2.1 Community Edition, Porto Theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can change cart page `Discount` label:

- Go to your theme `Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv`
- Find `Discount` word and change to `Member Discount`